# A tool for converting date copy into date format

Tags: data, file-converter

Is there a certain software which would take in a date as a string (Thursday, May 18, 2017 6:30:28am) and output something like 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' (moment.js format in this case, strftime is good too)

Web or command line, either way. If that'd be something designers could use in the workflow (Sketch/Zeplin plugin?) would be great as well.

The focus more on individual strings copies which are used in designs, not batch or anything which related to data sets.

Comment: The problem with such a program is that, like any free-format date parser, it could guess wrong in ambiguous situations (is "4/1/2014" on January 4th or April 1st? is "12/1/11" in 2011 or 2012? is "6:00" AM or PM?), and if the user doesn't understand the format (like your audience here, it seems), they won't be able to notice or fix mistakes. Other kinds of ambiguity include whether "May" is an abbreviated month name or a full month name and whether "12" indicates a value that would be zero-padded if it were smaller.